# How to display the username instead of the UID?

Tags: views, 8, nodes, users, comments

I created a view to display content in a table. I want to show the author of the last comment.
So I added the field "Comment Statistics: Uid of the last comment", but I wish to have the username in place of the UID.

How to do this ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a relationship to users in your view and then you should be able to access something like the username.

Comment: This does not work, I still have the uid 51 in the username.

Comment: What are the display options for that field?

Comment: @Kevin There is nothing but the user id (Group content Node) Comment Statistics: Uid of last comment (By)

Comment: Do you have an idea ?